# Any method to transform 'DGL.heterograph' to 'torch_geometric' graph?

Tags: graph, pytorch-geometric, dgl

I'm using dgl library since it was easy to understand..
But I need several modules in torch_geometric, but they don't support dgl graph.

Is there any way to change dgl graph to torch_geometric graph?
My datasets are built in dgl graph, and I'm gonna change them into torch_geometric graph when I load the dataset.

Comment: Might be able to do it now with `torch_geometric.utils.convert.from_dgl()` https://pytorch-geometric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/torch_geometric/utils/convert.html

Answer (score 0):

With a homogenous `networkx` graph as intermediate step, you could use the following methods:

1. [`dgl.to_homogenous`](https://docs.dgl.ai/en/latest/generated/dgl.to_homogeneous.html#dgl.to_homogeneous) to create a homogenous `dgl` graph instance
2. [`dgl.to_networkx`](https://docs.dgl.ai/en/latest/generated/dgl.to_networkx.html#dgl.to_networkx) to export the homogenous graph to a `networkx` graph
3. [`torch_geometric.utils.from_networkx`](https://pytorch-geometric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modules/utils.html?torch_geometric.utils.from_networkx#torch_geometric.utils.from_networkx) to read the homogenous `networkx` graph into `pytorch geometric`
4. [`torch_geometric.data.to_heterogenous`](https://pytorch-geometric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modules/data.html?torch_geometric.data.Data.to_heterogeneous#torch_geometric.data.Data.to_heterogeneous) to transform the homogenous graph into a heterogenous graph

As far as I saw neither of the packages has separate reader/writer for the heterogenous graphs. Hence, these extra steps are needed. Another alternative is the manual export of the tensor and the direct creation of the heterogenous `pytorch geometric` graph.